# Controlling large AC machinery using small DC power

Tags: fluid-pump

I am currently working on a water treatment machine where I need to have control over a pump and several solenoid valves. In order to do that, I am provided with a pre made controller bought from alibaba. The only problem is that the controller works with 24VDC while my pump and solenoid valves works with 230VAC..
How should I convert the 24VDC output from the controller so it can power my 230VAC pump and valves?
Is it possible to use a relay in which the 24VDC output from the controller is only used to power the relay's coil while the main circuit is powered by a separate AC power supply?

ps: I don't need to have a sophisticated control over the pump and valves, the only conditions are "on" and "off". There's no need for speed control or position control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of relays that are controllable from 24V.

You want to look for "coil voltage" or input voltage and the other ratings on the input side.

However when switching inductive loads like electric motors  you want to look out for the inrush current, relays that are built to withstand those are often called contactors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found a relay with 24 VDC coil voltage and with contact ratings of 10A 250VAC for cosφ = 1, and 7A 250VAC for cosφ = 0.4 . It is labeled as a general purpose relay. Can I use that instead of a contactor?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the controller to supply 24 V DC to relay coils. You should be able to find a relay with a 24 V DC coil that is suitable for a solenoid. A medium sized AC motor will need a motor starter, but a relay like the one you will find for the solenoid should be suitable to supply the coil of the motor starter.